# How to access .zip files of Downloads folder in target 31 Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, file

I wanted to move all my folders from downloads folder to app internal storage. I have a folder that contains .zip files.

`.listFiles()` doesn't return these files. What is the way to access it programmatically?

Below is the code that I used to check this.

```
 File[] filesList = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().listFiles();
    try {
        if (filesList != null) {
            for (File file : filesList) {
                if (file.getName().equals(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)) {
                    File[] downloadsFiles = file.listFiles();
                    if (downloadsFiles != null) {
                        for (File downloadsFile : downloadsFiles) {
                            if(downloadsFile != null) {
                                File[] files = downloadsFile.listFiles();
                                for(File f : files) {
                                    System.out.println(f.getName());
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE to let the user pick the folder. This can not be the public Download folder. Dont put them there.

Comment: I need to do the action in the background and not user pick the folder.

Comment: Who put your files in that folder?

Comment: This is an old app. These files were added before the storage restrictions came. @blackapps

Comment: Added by who was the question.

Comment: Programmatically it was added to the downloads folder.

Comment: Programmatically? Ok. But i wanted to know by which app. And what was the Android version when they were added?

Comment: SDK version 23 it was added.